# Use socket.io object in total.js

Tags: node.js, total.js

I'm using `socket.io` in total.js and want to use the `io` object in a module.

how can i access the `io` object in a module? (pass the object or set the global `framework` object?)

the initialization code:

```
require("total.js");

ON("load", function() {
    let io = require("socket.io")(this.server);
});

F.http("debug");
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to disable **WebSocket in Total.js framework**:
https://docs.totaljs.com/latest/en.html#api~FrameworkConfiguration~allow_websocket

**Initialization code for Socket.io**:

```
ON('ready', function() {
    // "IO" will be a global variable, so you can use it everywhere
    global.IO = require('socket.io')(F.server);
});
```

Comment: I read something about that is very bad to change global object, so now what is the best to do this?

Comment: Why is it bad? :-) Total.js uses a lot of global variables and I don't see any problem to create alias for your needs.

Comment: i read this article and it tells it's bad because of 3 reasons: https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/